# Is this proof about Cauchy's sequence correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers  and for each $n\in N$, let $f_n=a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_n$ and $g_n$=$|a_1|+|a_2|+...+|a_n|$. Prove that if $(g_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, then so is $(f_n)$.

My attempt:  Since $(g_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, we have,

$||a_1|+|a_2|+|a_3|+...|a_n||<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq m$

This implies $|a_1+a_2+...a_n|<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq m$

Thus $(f_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: Your idea (use the triangle inequality) is good, but you need to look at $|f_n-f_m|$ which isn’t quite what you have.

Comment: Ok thank you! I will look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$|f_n - f_m| = |a_{m+1} + \dots + a_n| \le |a_{m+1}| + \dots + |a_n| = |g_n - g_{m}| < \varepsilon$$